# VS2017 VB.NET Format String Not Working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

In a VS2017 VB.net webform app I'm trying to format a number, which is a string ("12345.0000"), into the format: "12345.00", i.e. 2 decimal places with no thousands separator. To do this I'm using the following line of code:-

```
rentalPriceVal = Format(memberPrices.RentalPrice, "0.00")
```

It returns "0.00".

I originally had `FormatNumber(memberPrices.RentalPrice, 2)` but that adds a locale-dependent thousands separator and decimal identifier.

I also tried:  `memberPrices.RentalPrice.ToString("0.00")` but that errors with "cannot cast String to IFormatProvider".

I'm at a loss. Have I messed up the syntax, is there a better way I haven't come across yet or is it just not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Convert the string to the number first, then format.

Comment: `Format(Val(memberPrices.RentalPrice), "0.00")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Decimal.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert your **string** to a **decimal**, then use `Decimal.ToString()` with "F2" as your [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

```
Dim price As Decimal
If Decimal.TryParse(memberprices.RentalPrice, price) Then
    Dim strPrice As String = price.ToString("F2")
    ' .. use "strPrice" somehow ...
    Debug.Print(strPrice)
End If
```